# Entering data with a ' (apostrophy) into SQL Server CE table

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

How could I go about entering data such as `"John's shoe"` into a SQL Server CE table (version 3.5) as the insert statements and so forth do not accept the use of the ' apostrophe in a statement such as the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO ShowsDB(Item) VALUES('+ "John's shoes" + "')
```

Comment: This allows for a SQL injection attack.  Use parameterized queries and you will both mitigate the attack **and** be able to insert single quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must avoid putting your data directly into your SQL, basically. Use parameterized SQL instead:

```
// I'm assuming you're opening the connection already
string sql = "INSERT INTO ShowDB(ITEM) VALUES (@Name)";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "John's shoes";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Using parameterized SQL has three benefits:

- Avoids [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Avoids unnecessary and dangerous string conversions (particularly for date/time types)
- Separates the "code" (SQL) from the data (parameters) which makes it easier to understand

Comment: ok, that seems to work but I am also try to check if the data already exists and that does not work: var rows = dataTable.Select("Item = " + "John's shoes");
                    if (rows.Length == 0)

Comment: @user1842134: You didn't mention using data tables. I'm not a big fan of `DataTable.Select` precisely because of this sort of thing. You may be best just iterating over the rows and checking each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL escaping is that quotes should be doubled, so your query becomes

```
INSERT INTO ShowsDB(Item) VALUES('+ "John''s shoes" + "')
```

Which is perfectly fine for things like running SELECT statements against a copy of the DB to diagnose problems, but should NEVER be used in actual production systems. Parameterized queries are your friend.

Comment: It's a bad habit to ever use this in any manner whatsoever. Parameterized queries should always be used 100% of the time, even if you know for a fact that your query is safe or that you're in a safe environment. All it takes is one person copy/pasting some code into your project, and you're now vulnerable to attack. If you get in the habit of parameterizing all the time (which is actually easier than fighting with all the quotes and character escaping anyway), you'll never make a mistake.